# Python, if statement to change a number

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and I made a script which searches for several lines that contain the "keyword" and then write/print in a new file the (previously) selected list-line (I used a second argument to select the line from the list).

Everything went well until I tried to add a statement in case my selected list-line is > than the actual len(list) then the selected list_line = len(list); for whatever reason, it does not work.

Can anyone please point out to why it is not working, this my script. Thanks a million for the help. (Here is [a link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/ActCat.out) with an example of the files that I am using as an input)

```
    import sys
    import re

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    line_select = int(sys.argv[2])


    newfile = str(filename) + ".3d"

    openold = open(filename,"r")
    opennew = open(newfile,"w")

    rline = openold.readlines()

    energies = []

    line_number = 0

    for line in rline:
        line_number += 1
        if re.search( r"SCF Done", line ):
            words = line.split()
            energy = float( words[4] )
            energies.append(str(line_number) + " : " + "The energy of the molecule is %f kcal mol-1" % energy)

    len_list = len(energies)

    if line_select > len_list:
        line_select = len_list

    print >>opennew, energies[line_select]

    openold.close()
    opennew.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: basically if I try a line_select that is > than the len_list I get: File "search10.py", line 32, in <module>
    print >>opennew, energies[line_select]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 4):

The last element of the `energies` list is actually `energies[len_list-1]`, since Python indexes start from 0.

So if you want to print "the last element of `energies`", you need to initialize `line_select` to one less than the list length:

```
if line_select >= len_list:
    line_select = len_list-1
```

Comment: I do not want to print just the last element, I want choose which element to print, and I control that using the second argument. However, I get an error when my line_select (second argument) if > than the len_list. Then I want to make an if statement that if my line_select > than len_list, then line_select = len(list), I tried just that in the code, but I keep getting an error.                File "search10.py", line 32, in <module> print >>opennew, energies[line_select] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I just did the change that you suggested, it works, thanks a million

Comment: Just click on the tick sign below the answer upvote counter, on the left of the answer text. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask (it'll come handy if you have more questions!)